# click event for parent and its children jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick

I have a table with `tr` having class `msgdetails`.Inside the `tr.msgdetails`,I have checkbox with class `sel_checkbox`.I have click events for both `tr element and checkbox` and I need to work it independently.If `checkbox` is clicked,event for checkbox should work and the other should work if `tr` is clicked other than checkbox.

My html is like this.

```html
<tr class="msgdetails even" role="row">
  <td width="20%">
    <div class="checkbox_div">
      <input  class="sel_checkbox" type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>some other data</td>
  <td>some  data</td>
</tr>
```

My jquery is like this:

```js
$("tr.msgdetails").click(function(e) {
  if ((e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==='checkbox') ||
      (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==='input'))
  {
    alert('checked checbox');  
  }
  else
  {
    alert('row clicked');
  }
  return false;
});
```

This works sometime but not working perfectly.Please help me

Comment: i suggest you use change event for checkbox than click

Comment: $("tr.msgdetails").click(function(e){
  if((e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==='checkbox')|| 
            (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==='input'))
        {
         alert('checked checbox');  
        }
        else
        {
         alert('row clicked');
        }
   return false;
});

Comment: *"This works sometime but not working perfectly"* - when doesn't it work, and why isn't it working perfectly?

Comment: When it's not working, what `e.target.tagName` is?

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsbin.com/sigena/edit?html,js,output

Comment: clicking the checkbox doesn't always mean is is checked. It would be unchecked if in checked state prior to click. Your posted code doesn't really make sense imho. And `e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==='checkbox'` makes less sense.  Anyway, we have no idea what is your expected behaviour???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code Snippet
------------**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/3vtc536q/)

**Html**

```
<div>

<table>
    <tr  class="msgdetails even" role="row">
   <td width="20%">
      <div class="checkbox_div">
           <input  class="sel_checkbox" type="checkbox">
      </div>
  </td>
  <td>some other data</td>
  <td>some  data      </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

</div>
```

### Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr.msgdetails").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.type==="checkbox"){
    var selCheckBox=$(e.target);
    if(selCheckBox.hasClass('sel_checkbox')){

          if($(selCheckBox).prop("checked")){
             alert('checked checbox'); 
            }
            else{
            alert('checkbox Unchecked');
            }
        }
    }else{
        /*if you dont want checkbox column row outside clicking to be disabled then*/
        var selCheckBox=$(e.target);
            var chk=$(selCheckBox).children().hasClass("sel_checkbox");
            if(chk){
                return false;
            }
      else{
                alert('tr clicked');
            }
    }


   });
});
```